# How to change the CRM Email Activity form based on email direction

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We're using the web interface or Dynamics CRM. We would like to change the email form based on the direction of the email.

E.g. if the direction is incoming, rename some labels, maybe hide a field, display the Actual Start as "received" etc.

Is there any way to do this without adding code to the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,

You will always have to add code for your requirement.

The easiest way is adding JavaScript to a form. [Form Scripting CRM 2011](http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/form-scripting-in-crm-2011/)
It's basically add a webresource containing your JavaScript code and then adding it to the form.